# Ensuring all waiting threads complete

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm building a system where the progress of calling threads is dependent on the state of two variables. One variable is updated sporadically by an external source (separate from the client threads) and multiple client threads block on a condition of both variables. The system is something like this

```
TypeB waitForB() { // Can be called by many threads.
    synchronized (B) {
        while (A <= B) { B.wait(); }
        A = B;
        return B;
    {
}

void updateB(TypeB newB) { // Called by one thread.
    synchronized (B) {
        B.update(newB);
        B.notifyAll(); // All blocked threads must receive new B.
    }
}
```

I need all the blocked threads to receive the new value of B once it has been updated. But the problem is once a single thread finishes and updates A, the waiting condition becomes true again so some of the other threads become blocked and don't receive the new value of B. Is there a way of ensuring that only the last thread that was blocked on B updates A, or another way of getting this behaviour?

Comment: Check what volatile keyword does in threading

Comment: He's doesn't seem to be synchronizing on `A` @DanielGabriel.

Comment: @DanielGabriel A = B doesn't change B.

Comment: Can you explain your concrete use case? In this toy example the problem you describe is solved by replacing `A <= B` with `A < B`.

Comment: It's often recommended to lock on objects that aren't visible outside their owner (lest some other code steal your lock and screw up your whole synchronization mechanism).  If `A` or `B` will be `return`ed, watch out.

Comment: TypeB is a security with a price and time-stamp. The condition (A <= B) is on the timestamp; the client threads only want prices that have been updated before the last call to 'waitForB'. Hence the condition must be A <= B and not A < B, but that would fix the issue yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got following idea: to keep counter of threads waiting for "good" value of B, first of them woken up will cache that good value and let other readers up to that moment read it. We keep new readers out of waiting loop till all previous round threads are done.

Here's outline of code:

```
final AtomicInteger A = new AtomicInteger(-1), B = new AtomicInteger(-1);
int cachedB = -1;

int readersCount;

int waitForB() throws InterruptedException { // Can be called by many threads.
    synchronized (B) {
        while (cachedB != -1) B.wait();

        readersCount ++;

        while (A.get() <= B.get()) { B.wait(); }

        if (cachedB == -1) {
            cachedB = B.get();
            A.set(B.get());

            readersCount--;
            if (readersCount == 0) { cachedB = -1; B.notifyAll(); }

            return B.get();
        } else {
            int ret = cachedB;

            readersCount--;
            if (readersCount == 0) { cachedB = -1; B.notifyAll(); }

            return ret;
        }
    }
}

void updateB(int newB) { // Called by one thread.
    synchronized (B) {
        B.set(newB);
        B.notifyAll(); // All blocked threads must receive new B.
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Victor, I like your solution! I think I've found another solution using a CyclicBarrier. I'll mark your solution as correct and post my solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is about to use an event based approach, where the threads want to know about the new `B` value just register about the changes! and the single thread just call(trigger) them out.
something like this.
first declare the event sign.

```
interface EventListener{
void onUpdate(TypeB oldOne,TypeB newOne);
}
```

then have an implementation as listener.

```
class ManyThread implements EventListener,Runnable{
...
private TypeA a;
  synchronized void onUpdate(TypeB oldOne,TypeB newOne){
    if(!oldOne.equals(newOne)){a=newOne;this.notify();}
  }

  public ManyThread(){SingleThread.registerListener(this);}
  public synchronized void run(){
     this.wait();//waiting for an event!
     //some business
  }
...
}
```

then provide the event publisher.

```
final class EventMgr{//would be as a singleton  guy too
  private EventMgr(){}
  static private java.util.List<EventListener> li=new java.util.ArrayList<EventListener>();
  static synchronized public void registerListener(EventListener e){li.add(e);}
  static synchronized void triggerListeners(TypeB oldOne,TypeB newOne){
    for(EventListener e:li){e.onUpdate(oldOne,newOne)}
  }
}
```

and simple trigger listeners by the `EventMgr` guy

```
class SingleThread{
   TypeB oldOne,B;
   void updateB(TypeB newB) { // Called by one thread.
      synchronized (B) {
        oldOne=B.clone();
        B.update(newB);
        //B.notifyAll();
        EventMgr.triggerListeners(oldOne,B);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately I'm not able to modify the calling client threads. I'm thinking of trying to use a CyclicBarrier or something similar. It's a tricky problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is 100% thread safe but I haven't found any issues yet. The idea is something like this:

```
CyclicBarrier barrier;
AtomicInteger count = 0;

TypeB waitForB() { // Can be called by many threads.
    synchronized (B) {
        count++;
        while (A <= B) { B.wait(); }
        count--;
    {
    if (barrier != null) { barrier.await(); }
    return B;
}

class UpdateA implements Runnable {
    void run() {
        A = B;
    }
}

void updateB(TypeB newB) { // Called by one thread.
    synchronized (B) {
        B.update(newB);
        barrier = new CyclicBarrier(count, new UpdateA);
        B.notifyAll(); // All blocked threads must receive new B.
    }
}
```